# Conversion function TO_INTEGER

Tags: vhdl

I have the following declarations

```
signal S: SIGNED(7 downto 0);
signal N: INTEGER;

N <= TO_INTEGER(S);
```

Will the `TO_INTEGER` function sign-extend `S` to a 32-bit integer?

Answer (score 1):

Integers are not binary based types, so no sign extension is needed. It simply converts the binary based sign representation to an integer that the current tool can use. All tool implementations I am aware of use 32 bit integers (the reference implementation actually doesnt use all 32 bits, it covers -2^31+1 to 2^31-1 to allow for 1s compliment implementations) . VHDL 2019 mandates 64 bit integers (but I am not aware of any tool that currently supports this).

Comment: Thanks. But isn't integer a signed number? That's why I thought that the signed signal would be sign extended first and then converted to integer.

Comment: Integers allow values in the range (typically) -2^31+1 to 2^31-1. How they are implemented (as signed, 1s compliment, 2s compliment, offset binary etc) is down to the tool maker and not defined by the VHDL language.

Answer (score 0):

This is implementation-depended. See the [Integer and Its Subtypes in VHDL](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/technical-articles/integer-and-its-subtypes-in-vhdl/).

*VHDL doesn’t specify the exact number of bits for the integer type*.

Answer (score 0):

**Question: Will the TO_INTEGER functiona sign extend 'S' to 32 bit integer?**

No.

From the IEEE Std 1076.3-1997 numeric_std package:

```vhdl
  -- Id: D.2
  function TO_INTEGER (ARG: SIGNED) return INTEGER is
    variable XARG: SIGNED(ARG'LENGTH-1 downto 0);
  begin
    if (ARG'LENGTH < 1) then
      assert NO_WARNING
          report "NUMERIC_STD.TO_INTEGER: null detected, returning 0"
          severity WARNING;
      return 0;
    end if;
    XARG := TO_01(ARG, 'X');
    if (XARG(XARG'LEFT)='X') then
      assert NO_WARNING
          report "NUMERIC_STD.TO_INTEGER: metavalue detected, returning 0"
          severity WARNING;
      return 0;
    end if;
    if XARG(XARG'LEFT) = '0' then
      return TO_INTEGER(UNSIGNED(XARG));
    else
      return (- (TO_INTEGER(UNSIGNED(- (XARG + 1)))) -1);
    end if;
  end TO_INTEGER;
```

The input is a value of array type signed. The leftmost element of the input (the sign) is examined in the last if statement. If '0' (a two's complement representation of a positive number or zero) no adjustment is made to the returned integer value resulting from converting the array value as an unsigned.  If '1' the two's complement of the converted array value as an unsigned is returned. Testing the sign bit is less effort than magnitude comparison to 0.

The TO_INTEGER unsigned function overload:

```vhdl
-- Id: D.1
  function TO_INTEGER (ARG: UNSIGNED) return NATURAL is
    constant ARG_LEFT: INTEGER := ARG'LENGTH-1;
    alias XXARG: UNSIGNED(ARG_LEFT downto 0) is ARG;
    variable XARG: UNSIGNED(ARG_LEFT downto 0);
    variable RESULT: NATURAL := 0;
  begin
    if (ARG'LENGTH < 1) then
      assert NO_WARNING
          report "NUMERIC_STD.TO_INTEGER: null detected, returning 0"
          severity WARNING;
      return 0;
    end if;
    XARG := TO_01(XXARG, 'X');
    if (XARG(XARG'LEFT)='X') then
      assert NO_WARNING
          report "NUMERIC_STD.TO_INTEGER: metavalue detected, returning 0"
          severity WARNING;
      return 0;
    end if;
    for I in XARG'RANGE loop
      RESULT := RESULT+RESULT;
      if XARG(I) = '1' then
        RESULT := RESULT + 1;
      end if;
    end loop;
    return RESULT;
  end TO_INTEGER;
```

which simply converts a binary value to a natural integer subtype value without regard to a sign.

There is no value range check that the converted binary value falls within the implementation defined type integer value range, and no implied underlying simulation kernel integer implementation.

VHDL doesn't expose the underlying implementation for type integer which is defined by a range of values and a set of operations. There's a minimum range that every implementation has to meet (-2147483647 to +2147483647, prior to -2019) which is one negative value short of that of a 32 bit binary two's complement integer representation.

Integers can be converted to binary values but don't otherwise have observable bits, scalar numerical types have no binary logical operators.